# Allow reducer to have access to state

Tags: redux

I have a reducer that maintains the currently visible item from a list of some sort, with a case for displaying the next and previous item:

```
export function currentIndex(state = null, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.INCREMENT:
       return state + 1
    case types.DECREMENT:
        return state - 1;
  }
}
```

I also have a `random` state which is initially false but when set to true I want the `currentListItem` reducer to be able to account for this and output a a random number instead.

Which is the most idiomatic way of doing this in redux?

Comment: Huh ? That's not tutorial code. Also why would it be irrelevant if it was ?? A single reducer is not an option as next and previous are dispatched via next and previous HTML buttons and random is a toggleable button. So when toggled on pressing next will produce a random item.

Comment: Well, it looks like a tutorial code (everyone increments numbers in their tutorial redux app). "displaying the next and previous item" --- it is expected to see the correspondingly named actions like `NEXT` and `PREV` or something. Otherwise, apologies :-)

Comment: "A single reducer is not an option" --- why is that? It does not matter, what emits the event/dispatches an action. The store structure should really not depend on your UI.

Comment: Because the next button dispatches an increment action. Pressing on random dispatches an action which sets a 'random' state to true. The user is still then able to click on next and previous. If random is true then I need to be able to change the behaviour of what prev and next does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiomatic solution is to transfer your reducer logic into a thunk using a middleware package such [redux-thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk) (or similar).

This allows you to treat special kinds of `actions` as functions which means you can extend a plain action with specific action-related logic. The example you give of needing to access the state to conditionally determine the action logic is an excellent use-case for redux-thunk.

Below is a example of how you might pull the logic out of your reducer into a thunk. You should note that, unlike reducers, thunks explicitly support fetching state and dispatching subsequent actions via the `getState` and `dispatch` functions.

**Thunk Example**

```
export const increment= () => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    const state = getState()
    const delta = (state.random) ? getRandomNumber() : 1
    dispatch({
      type: INCREMENT,
      delta
    })
  }
}

export function currentIndex(state = null, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.INCREMENT:
       return state + action.delta
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm already using thunks and had considered this as a solution but wasn't sure it was the way to go. I'll go with this. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Glad to be of help. Can you mark the answer as accepted and, if you are feeling generous, give it an upvote. Ta.